# iPhone - sorting a list of recurrent events

Tags: iphone, core-data

I have this list of recurrent events on a table at my app. Something like iCal. The user can set up events like:

- meeting next tuesday 3 pm
- meet wife every wednesday 6 pm
- take pills every day 1 pm
- take children saturday and sunday 9 am

The question is: how do I sort this to discover which will be the next event?

I am not sure the best way to create the core data entities.

Should I create the days of weeks as a second managed object on core data and create a to-many relationship to the first managed object representing the events (so each event can have one or more days of week objects). Should I create one managed object with boolean entities representing the days of week?

I can imagine different ways of doing this on core data, but I am not seeing how one can extract from core data a list sorted by event, I mean, a list that shows first the events close to today's date and last the event more distant.

What I ask here is not code, but rather, ideas on how this should be constructed... what do you guys suggest as the best way to put this together.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is have your "Event" entity in Core Data have a date and a recurrence attribute to it.  Set the date to when the event occurs and recurrence to how many seconds until the next time it occurs.  When the event happens, update the date with -dateByAddingTimeInterval with the current date and the recurrence interval.

You can then sort by date to get your next event.  If you want to show the event multiple times, like for a month calendar layout, loop on -dateByAddingTimeInterval: with the recurrence interval and mark it on your view during each iteration.